# NativeScript/Angular Page Routing (Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, nativescript

Does anyone have experience on what I should be researching to understand how to handle loops within routing? For instance, use Instagram's friend's list as an example. I'm going from myProfile to a friendsProfile and then again to one of theirFriendsProfile and so on for forever hypothetically. By hardcoding routes, I could only get to the first friendsProfile by explicitly stating a route to get there but no further.

routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", component: ItemsComponent },
{ path: "detail/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent },
{ path: "detail/:id/:url", component: ItemReferenceComponent },
{ path: "outfit", component: OutfitComponent },
{ path: "user", component: userComponent},
{ path: "user/detail/:id", component: ItemDetailComponent},
{ path: "user/detail/:id/:url", component: ItemReferenceComponent },
];
```

Attempting to navigate to a friend of a friend's profile results in a cannot match routes error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'items/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjoiNWY1ZWNlYWVkZDBkZjYwMDE3NDliOTQ3IiwiaWQiOiI1ZjVlY2VhZWRkMGRmNjAwMTc0OWI5NDgiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDI4MjU5NDcsImV4cCI6MTYwMjkxMjM0N30.vP3jDwvGp5HiP3Qq4OFohzM9e3H0zmb8pyJ8sNUD5bI/user/user'
```

I can recognize that this is a recursive issue since I cannot hardcode an infinitely long route for any possibility.